# Boot problems Ubuntu 12.10 Samsung Series 9 900x3c

Tags: 12.10

I just upgraded to 12.10 and I'm having considerable boot problems on my Samsung Series 9 900x3c. Most of the time nothing happens and a hard reboot has to be done. Every couple of times the Laptop actually boots but it still seems to be quite volatile as Kernel panics occur quite often. Any ideas how to fix these issues?

Thanks a lot in advance

Best regards

JO

Comment: Ok, it seems as if the old Kernel 3.2.0-31 still works without problems still I would like to be able to run the normally provided  Kernel. Any ideas suggestions?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem originates from the UEFI implementation done by Samsung. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit but deactivated UEFI before in the BIOS ever since then no problems.